# Different headers when printing

Tags: java, css, jsoup, openhtmltopdf

I need to export multiple HTML files into a single PDF one.
I'm using @page rules to apply a header.

I need to :

- Display the pagecount ( page n out of total)
- Display a different title in the header for each original HTML document

What I tried :

- Exporting each HTML separately:
  I get the good title but the pagecount is relative to the current HTML, not the global total.
- Using jsoup to gather every HTML in one document before exporting:
  I get the good pagecount but can't select which title to apply in the print header

I know about `@page:first` and `@page:last` but would like to be able to apply different styles for every page in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution !

You can specify some content to be on a named page :

`@page A { @top-left { content:"..." } }`

`div-A { page: A; }`

`<div-A>
Content that has a specific header
</div-A>`

Don't forget to apply some rules like "page-break-after: always"